# SQL Server Exception. Error No: 64

Tags: sql-server-2012, ado.net

I am getting below error when executing `ExecuteReader()` method.

In my .Net application when it is trying to execute a query it is throwing an 
exception

> Transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available). SQL Error No: 64

This is happening for only one query other queries works fine. There is no issue with query as I have tried executing that query in Query Analyzer and the same executes fine; result set is also very small and datatype, parameters are all fine.

Exception is:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `commandtimeout` property of the command object to `0` to wait until an exception is thrown. Also you can try to reboot your machine or you may try to restart you IIS Server.

Comment: I have tried executing the same query in Query analyzer and executes in milliseconds and also in the code it executes faster and throws the exception as well.
Here is the Exception Details:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified network name is no longer available

Comment: @AbhinawKaushik:- Did you try to restart your IIS server?

Comment: Yes, Restarted the SQL Server machine, Restarted the SQL Server Services, Restarted the WebServer machine, Restarted the IIS, Firewall is disabled on both the servers